# Adding Google Analytics to a Google Apps Script powered published web app is not working

Tags: google-apps-script, google-analytics

I have published a Google Apps Script powered web-app. I created a Google Analytics property/tag and added the code to the `html` file of my GAS web-app.

But it does not seem to be working. No analytics are being collectd.

My code:

`**code.gs**`:

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("index");
}
```

`**index.html**`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <!-- Google tag (gtag.js) -->
  <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=[REDACTED]"></script>
  <script>
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', '[REDACTED]');
  </script>
  <base target="_top">
</head>

<body>
  Hello
</body>

</html>
```

When I go to the published URL of the web-app, the console does not show any errors or anything related to `gtag`.

[image]

Comment: Google web apps are sandboxed iframes, which most likely causes issues with Google Analytics. You may find a solution [here though](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74520046/13771937)